# Grabbing the Coverage from Home Depot

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use Selenium, Python and xPath's to grab the coverage for materials that I'm scraping. The problem is I need to be able to different between product pages that don't have coverage as an option (i.e. a 2x4 vs paint).

I'm trying to get the coverage and the coverage label out of the following website.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-Premium-Plus-Ultra-8-oz-S410-7-Equestrian-Green-Satin-Enamel-Interior-Exterior-Paint-and-Primer-in-One-Sample-UL22316/304771954

This should also work on other pages that don't list coverage. Here is what I have:

```
try:
   element = "//div[@class='card__summary with-fade']//div[@class='col-6 specs__cell']"
   el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, element)
   default_coverage = el.text
   print('Coverage: ' + default_coverage)
  except NoSuchElementException:
    default_coverage = "No Coverage"
    print('Coverage: ' + default_coverage)
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this XPath to get above value:

```
'(//div[ .="Coverage Area (sq. ft.)" ]/following-sibling::div)[1]/text()'
```